# How Do I Delay A Script?

Tags: javascript, java

All I am trying to do is add a half or full second delay to a line of code all i want is to play one animation and let it finish the switch to another.

```
  if (keyWentDown("space")) {
    player.setAnimation("attack");
    player.x = player.x+0.001;
  }
  drawSprites();
}
```

Comment: You would use [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout).

Comment: I have already tried and failed to use that

Comment: Post your setTimeout implementation.

Comment: What exactly did you try? Include it in your original post.

Comment: Java or JavaScript?

Comment: Javascript and the original script is if (keyWentDown("space")) {
  player.setAnimation("attack");
  player.x = player.x+0.001;
  setTimeout(player.setAnimation("player_idle"));
}

Answer (score 0):

You can make a `delay(milliseconds)` function that returns a `Promise` and `await` it before running your code.

```
const delay = (time) => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, time))

async function YourCode() {
   // code before delay
   await delay(1000)
  // code after delay
}
```

Not the `async` keyword of the function to be able to `await` the `delay`